# i am not able to add and edit data in firebase cloud database with java script. i am able to select data but not able to add data

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, cloud

See i use following code to add data

```
db.collection("users").add({
                            email: $('#emailaddress-register').val(),
                            password: $('#password-register').val()
                         }).then((done) => {
                             alert('Account created sucessfully'+done);
                         }).catch(function (error) {
                              console.error('Error adding document: ', error)
                         });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the way you access the value from you email and password field, try with hard values

Comment: i already do it. still not working

Comment: like :
email: "my email",
password: "my password"

Comment: Yes i do same but not working

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on the info you provided :

```
 var config = {
          apiKey: "",
          authDomain: "",
          databaseURL: "",
          projectId: "",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: ""
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        const firestore = firebase.firestore();
        const settings  = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};

        firestore.settings(settings);
        let db = firebase.firestore();
```

It needs to have only one firestore instance :

```
var config = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const settings  = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};                
    db.settings(settings);
```

Then you can use what you got.

Comment: db.collection(...).push is not a function
Give me this error

Comment: See edits up above

Comment: db.ref is not a function

Comment: how did you define db ?

Comment: var config = {
   apiKey: "",
   authDomain: "",
   databaseURL: "",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
   messagingSenderId: ""
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 const firestore = firebase.firestore();
 const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
     
 firestore.settings(settings);
 let db = firebase.firestore();

Comment: Well you did not mention firestore

Comment: const firestore = firebase.firestore();
see i mention like above

Comment: i can select data with same declaration but add data not working

Comment: Well, you are defining two instances of firestore(), you only need one, so replace the first by db.

Comment: That is the reason why it does not upload

next time, give more code so that it is easier to adress

Comment: How ? give me sample code please

Comment: Edit your question and add your code to it

Comment: https://jalaybe.com/democode.txt

Comment: Edit on stack over flow please

Comment: Not able to edit

Comment: See the edit please

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I assume your config is actually filled, right ?

Comment: Yes i can select data. so but always i have filled config.

Comment: instead of "add()"
use 
db.collection("users").insert({

Comment: db.collection(...).insert is not a function